# invalid signature for travelpayouts hotel api

Tags: api, postman

I am trying to send a request to travelpayouts hotel search API, Two days ago I have been trying to get a result using the postMan program but a message appears that there is an error in the signature, although I followed the same instructions mentioned in the documentation for the API, if someone used this API before that please ask me to help me

[Api link that I have used](http://engine.hotellook.com/api/v2/search/start.json?iata=HKT&checkIn=2020-05-1&checkOut=2020-05-5&adultsCount=2&customerIP=188.161.219.141&childrenCount=1&childAge1=8&lang=ru&currency=USD&waitForResult=0&marker=279418&signature=7c15b78f6352bf632070945326fb972f)

Error message:
{
    "message": "Invalid signature",
    "status": "error",
    "errorCode": 3
}

Answer (score 1):

You could send your signature string to support@travelpayouts.com and mention a link to this question on SO, and we'll take a look at it and suggest how to make it work. As the signature string has your API token, it's better not to post it here.